# NGINX, Резка URL?

Tags: nginx

нужно убрать часть URL

```
https://videotranslation.ru/?meetingCode=jvanccsixh
https://videotranslation.ru/jvanccsixh
```

Убрать ?meetingCode=

```
rewrite ^/?meetingCode=(.*)$ /post$1 permanent;
```

Не работает
И сделать что бы оба раюотали

Comment: То же не работает `location ^~ /?meetingCode= {
    rewrite ^/?meetingCode=(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}`

Comment: `if ($request_uri ~ "/?meetingCode=(.*)") { return 301 $1; }` Не работает

Comment: `rewrite         ^(.*)$  $1/$arg_meetingCode  break;`

Comment: этот метод то же не рабочий